# perl module to find reverse dependencies (not only cpan)

Tags: perl

I need a static analysis tool (preferably command-line script as [scandeps.pl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-ScanDeps/script/scandeps.pl)) which can help to find reverse dependencies (not only cpan).

Example. One project has module `site::Import` and modules `site::Import::A` and `site::Import::B`, which have `use parent 'Site::Import'` in their code. I need that ouput of desired tool will be like

```
$ rdepsscan site/Import.pm
site::Import::A (site/Import/A.pm)
site::Import::B (site/Import/B.pm)
```

For now most relevant way that I found is `grep -r -E "use*.+site::Import" --exclude=\*.t .` But it's not so robust, e.g. one file can be twice in output. And it not covers situation when different modules can be in same file (though it's a bad practise)

Answer (score 2):

```
find -name '*.pm' -print0 |
   xargs -0 -l perl -e'require $ARGV[0]; CORE::say $ARGV[0] =~ s{^\./}{}r if $INC{"site/Import.pm"}' |
      sort -u |
         perl -ple'printf "%s (%s)\n", s{\.pm\z}{}r =~ s{/}{::}gr, $_'
```